# Capturing print messages sql to vb

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, message

I do have a stored procedure and the stored procedure will be printing an output. We copy paste the output from the stored procedure and run in the desired db. 
I want to capture the print messages and show it in a text box or label or whatever in a vb application.

Is there any way to capture the **print messages** from a procedure.

Comment: Do u absolutely have to use print? Why not SELECT or return value or output parameters?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter is correct.  What you propose is a kluge. Better to change your sproc to return a value and use it.

Comment: The process is for disabling logins, restoring it to another db. This is usually done in midnight. The purpose of printing is copying and pasting the output to the server we want and change the parameters from there and run it so that we can reduce the chances of making mistakes and can always double check before running the query.

Comment: Check this out. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2007/09/13/capture-print-messages-from-a-stored-procedure.aspx